# Refresh source of jquery autocomplete only after enter key ipressed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using asp.net mvc with jquery.

Now, in my project I am using jquery autocomplete. I want to refresh or search for the source ONLY after enter key is pressed. For the source, I am firing an ajax. Below is the code I have implemented till now.

```
 $("#Select").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Controller/GetSource',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    response($.map(data.data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.label, value: item.ID };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $("#Select").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {               
            $("#Select").val(ui.item.label);
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Autocomplete is designed to work as entries are typed in. It offers suggestions to help auto complete the details. So waiting until `Enter` is pressed sort of defeats the purpose. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could set the `minLength` to a high value and then trigger `search` upon `Enter`.

Comment: I am handling a large amount of data (nearly 1 million). So I don't want to fetch data every time user press a key. So my idea is to get as much long keyword from user as possible   and after user press enter, data will be fetched from server using that keyword.